# Update and Delete rows in GridView ASP.NET C# using stored procedure instead of using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

I have a GridView to manage my products. I have used store procedure to set data source for it. I also use `AutoGenerateDeleteButton` property for deleting each row of my GridView and now I want to use a stored procedure to delete the rows of my GridView when I click on "Delete" LinkButton. I tried some tutorial in other forum about ASP.NET but nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: Thank you for your information, I did it.

Comment: One more thing I'm trying to make a DropDownList for each row when I click on the "Edit" button to change "Images" for my products. I made a function to get all images url but when i set datasource for DropDownList I get error. Sorry if this comment make something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use item command. On item command you can pass the id of the row you want to delete as a command argument call your delete stored procedure  and then rebind the datasource on the gridview using your select stored procedure.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="Delete_Command" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DeleteRowID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub Delete_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)  
If e.CommandName.ToString = "Delete" Then 
Dim DeleteRowId As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString 
'call procedure here and pass argument delete row id 
'ExambleGridView.DataSource= Call procedure here to get the datasource 
ExambleGridView.DataBind()
End If
End Sub
```

C#

```
  protected void Delete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToString == "Delete") {
            string DeleteRowId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            //Call Procedure here to delete row
            ExampleGridview.Datasource=//Call Procedure here to get the datasource again
            ExampleGridView.Databind()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If possible, give an example.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="Delete_Command" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DeleteRowID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>


            If e.CommandName.ToString = "Delete" Then
                Dim DeleteRowId As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString
                'call procedure here and pass argument delete row id
                ' ExambleGridView.DataSource= Call procedure here to get the datasource
                ExambleGridView.DataBind()

Comment: Sorry for the not highligted code answer but is the best i can do on comment.

Comment: The if statement of course is located on codebehind in this function:
Protected Sub Delete_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)

Comment: Thank you everyone, my question has been solved. Your information give me more experiences when i work with gridview. I'm just a person who like C# and ASP.NET website and i learn ASP.NET myself. So if I make something wrong please forgive me. Thank you so much, wish everyone have a good day.